# Controlar los mensajes de que se genera en el formulario cuando falta algún campo llenar, con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Esta es mi primera publicación, no me maten por favor xD.!. Bueno vallamos al punto, sucede que quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de que con Javascript pueda manejar los mensajes de alertas(si es que así se llaman), de todos modos dejo la imagen adjunta para que me entiendan mejor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema en si es que estos mensajes se originan al activarse el evento submit y yo quiero controlar esos mensajes, es decir que poder mostrarlas con cualquier evento, sin necesidad de que se muestre con el evento submit, espero me entiendan.

Se que este mensaje se obtiene al usar el atributo HTML required, pero como les comentaba, quisiera una manera de yo generar con javascript esas alertas para poder activarlas con cualquier evento y no solo con el de tipo submit.

Muchas gracias a todos espero me puedan ayudar y como les repito no me maten es mi primera pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Si**, como bien explica **[este link](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145)**, se puede hacer con `JS`.

Para ello se tiene que poner un id en el input y luego aplicarle el mensaje al evento:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('username');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Username should only contain lowercase letters. e.g. john');
}
```

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" pattern="[a-z]{1,15}" required />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Solo la segunda opción me funciono, asi q edito  y si la consigo hacer andar lo vuelvo a poner

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.!

Comment: No hay porque, si te sirvió alguna respuesta, no olvides marcarla como correcta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para desplegar dichos mensajes en cualquier momento, debes hacer uso de [`report​Validity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity)

#### Ejemplo

```js
document.getElementById('name')
  .reportValidity()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.!